# JavaScript: tail a local file

Tags: javascript, file, qml, tail

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044799/continiously-tail-a-local-file-for-new-lines-using-javascript-in-a-browser) question I noticed - despite the initial question - the solution provided works only for remote files unless you have a webserver.

Instead I'm looking for a solution (that doesn't use Node.js) to "tail -f" a local file (on the same machine where the script runs) in order to read its changes. *The script runs in a QML item*, so no browsers nor webservers are involved.

The file might be updated quite quickly: i.e. several times per second, but with few chars at time only.

I'm able to read the file's content using an `XMLHttpRequest` but it seems it doesn't fit for my purpose.

### UPDATE

After the downvote and the closing request I try to explain in other words.

I'm working on a [commercial device](http://www.microtronix.com/fpga-ip-hd-video-products/hd-video-products/dx-4400-3g-sdi-text-amp-graphics-inserter-with-pip-osd-amp-sdi-loop-output) that offers a loader for QML objects *only*. I cannot write C++ applications, there's no compilers, etc... 
Into `/tmp` folder there's a file that is continuously updated by a bash script.  In my QML object I need to parse each line as soon as it is appended. The Qt version is 4.x and QtQuick is 1.1.

So I'm asking a way to achieve this goal with these constraints.

Comment: You said "a pure JavaScript way" but (a) XMLHttpRequest isn't "pure" JavaScript and (b) "pure" JavaScript has no input/output features at all, it depends entirely on the host environment to provide an API.

Comment: It's written in the question: it's a QML object. Sorry for the misleading words, I will correct them. I mean without Node.js.

Comment: I know practically nothing of QML but a poke at the documentation says you should read the file from the main language for your app and then expose it to JS via a [property binding and/or signal handler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-expressions.html).

Comment: @Quentin yes, that's the standard way and I'm doing it daily. This time I *cannot* use a backend C++ application. Hence I asked how to do this in JS only.

Comment: "JavaScript has no input/output features at all, it depends entirely on the host environment to provide an API."

Comment: If that's the answer, please don't comment and create an answer.

Comment: ECMAScript is the underlying language for JavaScript (typically written as "javascript" to mean implementations that support a DOM and i/o). Both require a host environment. ECMAScript has zero i/o, javascript has i/o depending on the implementation (e.g. various browsers, node, etc. see [*List of ECMAScript implementations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines)).

Comment: Simply put, in a web browser, using javascript alone, you can't perform actions on local files as it would be a huge security risk. This answer of mine shows somewhat what can be done when it comes to file access/read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031719/read-csv-file-with-javascript-into-a-key-value-pair-array/22033170#22033170